# Carga simultánea de archivos

Tags: javascript, css

Para cargar simultaneamente los archivos necesarios para mi aplicación, utilizo el siguiente `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link id="SKIN" rel="stylesheet" charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>   
    <script src="config.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script src="spin.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

    <script id="ROUTIE" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script id="CORE" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script id="APP" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>

    <!-- Para seleccionar la versión, y mostrar el spinner. -->
    <script>
// Escogemos la APP. Este código DEBE IR AQUÍ.
( function( ) {
  if( CONDICIONES )
    window.APP = 'FSKIN' ;

  // Aquí va otro código, donde obtengo el valor del skin.

  document.getElementById( 'SKIN' ).href = skin;
  document.getElementById( 'ROUTIE' ).src = 'routie-0.3.2.min.js';
  document.getElementById( 'CORE' ).src = 'core.js';
  document.getElementById( 'APP' ).src = 'full.js';
} )( );
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="webix/webix.js"></script>

    <script>
// Lanzamiento.
webix.ready( function( ) {
  APP.Run( );
} );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

La secuencia de bajada que obtengo es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se observa, las fuentes son las últimas en descargarse, tiempo después de terminar la descarga del archivo `webix.css`.

Estoy aprendiendo Javascript. No se si esto es una consecuencia del `.css` utilizado (reconozco mi ignorancia en `.css`), o algo relativo al código que uso.

Ahora, las preguntas:

1. ¿ Porqué ocurre este desfase en el inicio de la carga de las fuentes ?
2. ¿ Como puedo solucionarlo ?

**EDITO**

No me fijé en el *inicializador* de la descarga. El texto completo es

> webix_debug.js:4961

y el contenido de esa línea en cuestión es

```
var x = this._viewobj.parentNode.offsetWidth||0;
```

No veo que exista relación entre esto y el desfase en el inicio de la carga.

Comment: Antes de que un documento se renderiza ocurren tres fases: descarga ,parseo y ejecución (este último solo para scripts). El documento HTML se descarga y se empieza a leer línea por línea. Cuando encuentra un tag `link`, `script` o `img`, se descarga el contenido del recurso externo y se parsea. Lo interesante aquí es que **no se asegura el orden** en el que **termina la descarga** de los scripts, estilos o imágenes.

Comment: Si un script puesto al último es más ligero que el primero, se descargará primero. En el caso de **ejecución** de scripts, se puede recurrir al atributo `defer`: `<script defer src="/js/algo.js"></script>`. Lo que hace este atributo es que no bloquea la carga del documento para ser ejecutado, si no que espera a que se descargue y parsee todo el documento y allí se empiezan a ejecutar los scripts en el orden establecido (antes que se dispare `DOMContentLoaded`).

Comment: @Guz Gracias por tus comentarios. Eso que indicas lo realizo añadiendo el atributo `src` a mano, lo cual hace que automáticamente se inicie la descarga. El ultimo trozo del archivo es una llamada a `webix.ready( callback )`, lo cual me garantiza que no se llamará al *callback* hasta que todo el contenido esté descargado, incluidos los scripts que bajo *a mano*. Es igual que `$.ready( )`. Lo *curioso* son las fuentes. Si se indican en el `.css` ... ¿ no deberían de bajarse justo después de bajar el `.css` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vale, ya lo descubrí.

Hice un

```
`setTimeout( function( ) { ...Algo que imprime... }, 3000 );
```

y las fuentes comenzaron a cargarse **3 segundos mas tarde** que antes.

Buscando en Internet, usando los términos

> javascript preload font

Me llevó a [`Fighting the @font-face FOUT`](https://www.paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/)

En dicha página se indica que el comportamiento de los *browsers* varía:

- Intnernet Explorer descarga la fuente en cuanto ve algún elemento
  `@font-face`
- Gecko, Webkit, y Opera, no descargan la fuente hasta que encuentran algún elemento HTML con un estilo que implica un elemento `@font-face`.
- Otros *browsers* pueden tener otros comportamientos.

En la fecha del artículo, Octubre del 2009, no había ningún método estándar para *precargar* una fuente.

Comment: Es decir, en Gecko, Webkit y Opera se implementa una especie de lazy loading al cargar fuentes. Interesante, gracias por el enlace. Si viene de Paul Irish es una lectura de calidad ;)