# Uso de <link="preload" ... > para la carga adelantada de fuentes

Tags: html5

Estoy optimizando la carga de mi página web. He descubierto el [atributo `<link="preload" ... >`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content), y estoy intentando usarlo. Pero los resultados **no** son los esperados.

Este es mi `HTML`, donde indico la *precarga* de las fuentes. En total, se cargan 8 archivos, en varias fases:

1. `preload` de las fuentes.
2. Carga `async` de los *scripts* Javascript.
3. Ejecución del Javascript *embebido* en la página y asignación de `DOMContentLoaded`.
4. Carga asíncrona de un archivo `.json` mediante `XMLHTTPRequest`.
5. Carga asíncrona de la hoja de estilos.

   ```
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <link rel="preload" href="fonts/Roboto-Medium-webfont.woff2" as="font">
       <link rel="preload" href="fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff2" as="font">
       <link id="CSS" rel="stylesheet">
       <script src="webix.js" async></script>
       <script src="login.js" async></script>
       <script src="candidate.js" async></script>
       <script src="admin.js" async></script>
       <script src="super.js" async></script>
       <script>
   ( function( ) {
       const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest( );

       document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function( ) {
           const css = document.getElementById( 'CSS' );

           xhr.addEventListener( 'load', function ( ) {
               FullPageLoaded( );
           } );

           xhr.open( 'GET', 'login', true );
           xhr.send( );

           window.onload = FullPageLoaded;
           css.onload = FullPageLoaded;
           css.href = 'skins/material.css';
       } );
   } )( );
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
   ```

En Firefox, obtengo los siguientes resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual es mas o menos lo esperado, puesto que en la sección de compatibilidad se indica que Firefox **no** soporta `<link="preload" ... >` <sub>(desilusión ...)</sub>.

Sin embargo, en Google Chrome, obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se observa que se realizan **2 peticiones** para cada archivo de fuentes: una al principio, al encontrar el `<link="preload" ... >`, y otra **al final**, cuando realmente se usan dichas fuentes.

Además, Google Chrome me muestra los avisos

> The resource http://localhost:8080/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff2 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
> The resource http://localhost:8080/fonts/Roboto-Medium-webfont.woff2 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Cuando el tiempo total de carga y renderizado de la página no llega siquiera a 1 segundo.

- ¿ Estás 2 peticiones por cada archivo de fuente es el comportamiento esperado al usar `<link="preload" ... >` ?
- ¿ Que significan esos avisos de Google Chrome ?
- ¿ Como elimino dichos avisos ?

<sub>Relacionado: [Carga simultánea de archivos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/49966/19610).</sub>

Comment: yo estoy teniendo el mismo problema, aun usando el `type="font/woff2"`y el `crossorigin="anonymous"` en el `<link>` se realizan 2 llamadas por cada fuente en el sitio..! Hay otra manera de evitar esto.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo esto podría responder tus tres preguntas a la vez

> ### **Caso de uso: Fuentes**
>
> Las fuentes son un excelente ejemplo de recursos de detección tardía que se deben obtener. Con frecuencia, se encuentran al final de uno de varios archivos `CSS` que cargan una página.
>
> A fin de reducir la cantidad de tiempo que el usuario debe esperar el contenido de texto de tu sitio, así como para evitar cambios molestos entre las fuentes del sistema y las que configuraste para el sitio, puedes usar  en tu código `HTML` con el objetivo de informar de inmediato al navegador que se necesita una fuente.
>
> ```html
> <link rel="preload" as="font" crossorigin type="font/woff2" href="myfont.woff2">
> ```
>
> Ten en cuenta que el uso de `crossorigin` aquí es importante. Sin este atributo, el navegador ignora la fuente precargada y se realiza una nueva operación `fetch`. Esto es porque se espera que el navegador obtenga las fuentes anónimamente y la solicitud de precarga se hace anónima solo mediante el atributo `crossorigin`.
>
> [Web fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/resource-prioritization?hl=es#caso_de_uso_fuentes)